# switch database stage in rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

It seems that the database used to display the data is different from the one I can work with in rails console.

I have tried running `rails dbconsole` and I get:

```
Couldn't find database client: sqlite3. Check your $PATH and try again.
```

My test and development database adapter are SQlite3 and my production adapter is MYSQL.

I need my rails console to connect to my production database.

Comment: "Stage" is the wrong word; you're looking to switch "environments". Your environments probably shouldn't be using different database engines, you should fix that in your `config/database.yml`. It's not clear whether you have a functional SQlite3 database in development which is populated, or a functional MySQL database in production which is populated. Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that to me.
Both of the databases are populated. I was guessing that the db I was connecting to in rails console was the development, it is the only explanation I could think of. I was able to connect to production with the answer you gave below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to connect to your production database, you need to set the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable to `production` before executing the `console` or `dbconsole` commands.

The "Rails console" and the `dbconsole` command reference different things:

If you want to connect directly to your database to execute SQL statements, use

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rails dbconsole
```

If you're trying to load the "Rails console", that is, an interactive Ruby shell with access to your Rails environment, run

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production ./script/rails console
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to work with the production db!
Should I run a similar command to seed data to the production db, because running rake db:seed loads into a different db. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The environment is *always* specified via the `RAILS_ENV` environment variable. If you want to seed the production database, you must run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:seed`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following command.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails c
```